# Acessar dados dentro de array em PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Eai galera, tudo certo?

Estou com um problema em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo.
Eu recebo um formulário onde o usuário informa os dados mas neste form, é possível que ele clique em um botão para inserir novos inputs e informar outros dados.

O array que estou utilizando como teste é esse:
(Mas pode variar conforme o usuário insira outros campos).

```
array:8 [▼
    "name" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "101"
        1 => "102"
        2 => "103"
    ]
    "gate" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "1"
        2 => "1"
    ]
    "chairs_initial" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "80"
        1 => "161"
        2 => "242"
    ]
    "chairs_final" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "160"
        1 => "241"
        2 => "322"
    ]
    "tickets_avaliable" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "80"
        1 => "80"
        2 => "80"
    ]
    "price_full" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "40"
        1 => "40"
        2 => "40"
    ]
    "price_half" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "20"
        1 => "20"
        2 => "20"
    ]
    "plant_sector" => array:3 [▼
        0 => UploadedFile {#291 ▶}
        1 => UploadedFile {#303 ▶}
        2 => UploadedFile {#287 ▶}
    ]
]
```

E nele eu percorro da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
foreach ($temp_sectors as $i => $temp) {
    foreach ($temp as $j => $val) {
        $sec[$j] = $val;
        dd($sec); 
    }
}
```

E tenho sempre o retorno da primeira posição do 'name' assim:

```
0 => "101"
```

Sem acesso ao 'gate', 'chairs_initial', 'chairs_final'...
Não sei se há outra maneira, mas o que eu gostaria de montar é separar estes dados conforme a posição em um array temporário, exemplo:

```
array:0 [▼
    "name" => "101"
    "gate" => "1"
    "chairs_initial" => "80"
    ...
]
array:1 [▼
    "name" => "102"
    "gate" => "1"
    "chairs_initial" => "161"
    ...
]
array:2 [▼
    "name" => "103"
    "gate" => "1"
    "chairs_initial" => "242"
    ...
]
```

Para mim poder após isso realizar um foreach neste array temporário e inserir os dados em meu banco de dados.
Não sei se há uma outra forma mais simples, mas se houver gostaria de entende-la.

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi se as chaves do array também são dinâmicas, mas se apenas a quantidade de elementos dos arrays forem dinâmicos você pode usar o método [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) para juntar todas as variáveis em apenas um elemento do array.

Ex.:

```
<?php 

$input = [
    "name" => ["101", "102", "103"],
    "gate" => ["1", "1", "1"],
    "chairs_initial" => ["80", "161", "242"],
    "chairs_final" => ["160", "241", "322"],
];

$temp = array_map(function ($name, $gate, $ch_init, $ch_final) {
    return [
        "name" => $name,
        "gate" => $gate,
        "chairs_initial" => $ch_init,
        "chairs_final" => $ch_final,
    ];
}, $input['name'], $input['gate'], $input['chairs_initial'], $input['chairs_final']);

var_export($temp);
```

Vai printar:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'name' => '101',
        'gate' => '1',
        'chairs_initial' => '80',
        'chairs_final' => '160',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'name' => '102',
        'gate' => '1',
        'chairs_initial' => '161',
        'chairs_final' => '241',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'name' => '103',
        'gate' => '1',
        'chairs_initial' => '242',
        'chairs_final' => '322',
    ),
)
```

[Código funcionando...](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/FumblingInsubstantialIntegrationtesting)

Comment: As chaves não são dinamicas, era exatamente isso! Haha. Não me lembrava do array_map. Muito obrigado!