# Como fazer para juntar resultados de diferentes foreach em um array?

Tags: php, json, array, foreach, dom

Estou pegando informações de filmes em cartaz de um site de cinema, usando Simple Html Dom.

```
<?php 
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html("http://arcoplex.com.br/?lang=059");
```

Para pegar os títulos dos filmes eu faço:

```
foreach($html->find('.Cartaz .filme-single-name text') as $titulo) {
    echo $titulo . '<br>';
}
```

Para pegar o src das imagens da capa dos filmes eu faço:

```
foreach($html->find('.Cartaz .filme-img') as $capa) {
    echo $capa->src . '<br>';
}
```

Para pegar o link dos filmes eu faço:

```
foreach($html->find('.Cartaz .mais_info a') as $link) {
    echo $link->href . '<br>';
}
```

O resultado é assim:

[image]

Sabendo disso tudo, como faço para juntar em um array/json as informações de cada filme juntas?

Exemplo:

```
{
  filmes: {
    1: {
      titulo: 'A FREIRA',
      capa: 'http://arcoiriscinemas.com.br/2014/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/mini2-1-175x285.jpg',
      link: 'http://arcoplex.com.br/filme/a-freira-2/?lang=059'
    },
    2: ...............,
    3: ...............,
    etc,
  }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Acessar dados dentro de array em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331761/acessar-dados-dentro-de-array-em-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $titulo =  $html->find('.Cartaz .filme-single-name text');
    $capa =  $html->find('.Cartaz .filme-img');
    $link = $html->find('.Cartaz .mais_info a');
    $novaArray = array();
    foreach($titulo as $key => $value) {
        $novaArray[$key] = array('titulo'=>$titulo[$key],'capa'=>$capa[$key],'link'=>$link[$key]);
    }
    print_r($novaArray)

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) passando `null` como callback

```
$unido = array_map(
    null,
    $html->find('.Cartaz .filme-single-name text'),
    $html->find('.Cartaz .filme-img'),
    $html->find('.Cartaz .mais_info a')
);
```